# FreeBSD 10.3 PHP Start error

Tags: php, module, freebsd

Been few years since I was administrating FreeBSD and now I found one old rig with AMD Athlon x64/1GB DDR2, so I decided to give it a run. Now I got FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p11. I installed MariaDB 5.5, Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6. Than I put PhpMyAdmin from the ports. Everything looks ok until I tried to open phpmyadmin and got:

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

```
[root@devilix(/usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts)]: ls
bcmath.so       ftp.so          mcrypt.so       pdo_odbc.so     snmp.so         wddx.so
bz2.so          gd.so           mysql.so        pdo_sqlite.so   soap.so         xml.so
calendar.so     gettext.so      mysqli.so       phar.so         sockets.so      xmlreader.so
ctype.so        gmp.so          opcache.so      posix.so        sqlite3.so      xmlrpc.so
curl.so         hash.so         openssl.so      pspell.so       sybase_ct.so    xmlwriter.so
dom.so          iconv.so        pcntl.so        readline.so     sysvmsg.so      xsl.so
enchant.so      imap.so         pdf.so          recode.so       sysvsem.so      zip.so
exif.so         json.so         pdo.so          session.so      sysvshm.so      zlib.so
fileinfo.so     ldap.so         pdo_dblib.so    shmop.so        tidy.so
filter.so       mbstring.so     pdo_mysql.so    simplexml.so    tokenizer.so
[root@devilix(/usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts)]:
```

I got them but it cannot work with them. 
Here is one line from /var/log/httpd-error.log. For all modules is the same just don't want to spam.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts/xsl.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/20131226-zts/xsl.so: Undefinned symbol "executor_globals_id" in Unknown on line 0

In my php.ini file the only thing that I found is `extension=php_*.dll`. DLL ?!? Still headbanging and cannot fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the `php.ini` file is for Windows, not Unix.

Comment: Yeah. But I`m installing the PHP5.6 from /usr/ports/lang/php56/ and the extensions from /usr/ports/lang/php56-extensions/. I don`t get it how it happens like this. I tried fixing extension=mbstring.so and uncomment it but nothing changed.

Comment: try restoring your php.ini to the default then...(cp /usr/local/etc/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php.ini)